# Отправка HTTP POST с Angular на Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, angular2, typescript, spring-boot

Всем привет. Пишу REST приложение с Angular и Java Spring Boot. 
База есть, сущности тоже. Методы GET и DELETE отлично работают. А вот с POST  проблема. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём дело.

Ошибка -

> status: 415
>   error: "Unsupported Media Type"
>   message: "Content type 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8' not supported"
>   path: "/users"

Клиентская часть сервиса отправки:

```
createNewUser(user: User){
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post
    ('http://localhost:8080/users',   JSON.stringify(user));
}
```

Вызов сервиса:

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.registrationForm);
    const formData=this.registrationForm.value;
    this.usersService.getUserByLogin(formData.login).subscribe((data:User)=> {
        if (data!=null) {
            alert('A user with this username exists.');
        } else {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(formData));
            this.usersService.createNewUser(formData)
                .subscribe((user:User) => {
                    alert('new user Added!');
                });
        }
    })
}
```

Серверная часть:

```
    @PostMapping()
public User create(@RequestBody User user)
{
    user.setCreationDate(LocalDateTime.now());
    return userRepository.save(user);
}
```

Тестил отправку данных через POSTMAN, всё работает корректо. Не понимаю, в чём дело

Answer (score 1):

Ваш метод REST по умолчанию ждет mediaType application/json, а вы в него шлете text/plain, о чем он в сообщении честно написал.

Comment: Читать я умею, спасибо. Но я отправляю джейсон
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users',   JSON.stringify(user));

Comment: Проверьте какой у вас mediaType в хидере пишется

Comment: `const myHeaders=new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type','application/json');
        return this.http.post
        ('http://localhost:8080/users',   JSON.stringify(user), {headers:myHeaders});`
    
Если кидать так, то 400ю выдаёт и ругается на корсы, хотя я  их конфиг подрубил и  GET и DELETE работают прекрасно @Z.John

Comment: GET и DELETE у вас в REST  работают скорей всего через @PathVariable{"id"}, а здесь вы передаете @RequestBody объект в виде JSON. Попробуйте сформировать header так:`const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })`.

Comment: в комментарии выше я указал и этот способ, не работает.

Comment: а так да, GET и DELETE работают через  @PathVariable{"id"}

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, в post надо передавать не строку (`JSON.stringify(user)`), а объект. Тогда Angular сам его сериализует и выставит правильный заголовок

```
createNewUser(user: User){
    console.log(user);
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/users', user);
}
```